# How to Deserialize a XML response when the root node is a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string, root-node

The Microsoft Cognitive Text Translator API gives a response in the following format:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">nl</string>
```

I was trying to deserialize it with the following code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlResult); // xmlResult is the xml string above
var textReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
var result = serializer.Deserialize(textReader) as string;
```

But this will result in an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 23). ---> System.InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.

I was thinking of wrapping the api response xml in another root node, so I could parse it to an object. But there must be a better way to solve this.

Comment: Do you want to just get the `nl` from the string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, just the `nl` part

Comment: Try `var result = XElement.Parse(xmlResult).Value;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Microsoft Cognitive Text Translator API gives a response in the following format

Considering it is always valid XML fragment having a single string node, you may safely use

```
var result = XElement.Parse(xmlResult).Value;
```

When parsing the XML string with `XElement.Parse`, you do not have to care about the namespace.

Comment: @Charles Mager's answer is also correct, but I prefer this answer because it is a single line code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is the namespace. If you serialised a value using that serialiser, you'd get:

```
<string>nl</string>
```

So set the default namespace to the one in your XML:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string),
     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/");
```

And use that:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlResult))
{
    var result = (string)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/asySqr) for a working demo.

Comment: I was looking for that `defaultNamespace` attribute, but Intellisense didn't show it untill I entered a string. Thanks for the solution :)